# Trouble saving different setTitle with user defaults for my buttons

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults, persistent-data

I'm developing a build your own adventure app with 2 buttons that change their `.setTitle` every time they are being pressed. My app is ready- everything works as it should. Whenever a button is pressed, the the story `textview` changes, and my buttons present new titles. The only thing I have left is finding a way to save the most recent titles my buttons presented
for when users return to the app after closing it.

Using `UserDefaults.Standard` has helped me save the story `textview`, but so far I couldn't find a way to save the changing titles (`.setTitle`) for my buttons.
This is how I managed to save the `textview`:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
func savePageTopText() {
    defaults.set(storyTextView.text, forKey: "topText")

}

func checkTopPageText() {
    let pageText = defaults.value(forKey: "topText") as? String
    storyTextView.text = pageText
}
```

I then added the `savePageTopText()` to each of my buttons, and the `checkTopPageText()` to `viewDidLoad.This` is how the titles for my buttons are coded, and they change whenever a button is pressed:

```
let answer1a = "Turn left"
let answer1b = "Turn right"
let answer2a = "Keep driving!"
let answer2b = "Pull over!"

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 1 && storyIndex == 1 {
        storyTextView.text = story3
        topButton.setTitle(answer3a, for: .normal)
        bottomButton.setTitle(answer3b, for: .normal)                     
        savePageTopText()     
    }
}
```

I hope I'm being clear enough about everything- doing my best.
When users close the app, how can I make sure they return to the same and most recent titles the buttons presented?
How do I SAVE the buttons setTitle with user default?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all the things correctly like saving but while fetching you are doing the mistake. `UserDefaults` has the type to fetch the data like `String`, `Int`, `Array`, etc.

So here is how you can fetch the saved `String`.

```
func checkTopPageText() {
    storyTextView.text = defaults.string(forKey: "topText")
}
```

Just like you need to know that what data is being saved and then only you can fetch using appropriate methods.

Comment: Thank you, Sohil- but could you please show me how to fetch the *title for my buttons?* My struggle is with saving & fetching the .setTitle
Thanks a lot!